# How can I install a file to /boot in yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I need to add a file to the /boot directory produced by a yocto build.  I've created a recipe that is trying to do this:

```
SRCREV = "48cabcbc64484ca6c201746e526a11b4b43eb359"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

SRC_URI += "file://0001-uEnv.patch file://0002-disable-boot-interrupt.patch file://uEnv.txt"
FILES_${PN} += "/boot/uEnv.txt"

do_install_append() {
    install -m 0744    ${WORKDIR}/uEnv.txt       ${D}/${base_prefex}/boot
}
```

This recipe does some patching of u-boot too, but for now I'm just interested in the parts that are trying to add uEnv.txt to the boot directory.  I know this recipe is being processed.  If I rename the uEnv.txt file, for example, it throws an error.  So I know it's trying to install it.  But when I examine the rootfs created by yocto, the file is missing.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Maybe the problem is with `${D}/${base_prefex}/boot` and I'm just not putting it in the right place?  I've tried putting it in other places, though, like `${D}${sysconfdir}/` without success.

Comment: `${base_prefix}`, not `${base_prefex}`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some idea that you can try:

`u-boot` already have a variable to work with Env files (Check `poky/meta/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot.inc`)

It checks for `UBOOT_ENV` variable if it is present and it copies it to `/boot`:

```bash
do_install() {
...
if [ -n "${UBOOT_ENV}" ]
    then
        install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/${UBOOT_ENV_BINARY} ${D}/boot/${UBOOT_ENV_IMAGE}
        ln -sf ${UBOOT_ENV_IMAGE} ${D}/boot/${UBOOT_ENV_BINARY}
    fi
...
}

do_deploy() {
...
if [ -n "${UBOOT_ENV}" ]
    then
        install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/${UBOOT_ENV_BINARY} ${DEPLOYDIR}/${UBOOT_ENV_IMAGE}
        rm -f ${DEPLOYDIR}/${UBOOT_ENV_BINARY} ${DEPLOYDIR}/${UBOOT_ENV_SYMLINK}
        ln -sf ${UBOOT_ENV_IMAGE} ${DEPLOYDIR}/${UBOOT_ENV_BINARY}
        ln -sf ${UBOOT_ENV_IMAGE} ${DEPLOYDIR}/${UBOOT_ENV_SYMLINK}
    fi
...
}
```

I assume that your recipe is a `bbappend` for `uboot` because it has a patch.

So you can try the following:

```bash
SRCREV = "48cabcbc64484ca6c201746e526a11b4b43eb359"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

SRC_URI += "file://0001-uEnv.patch file://0002-disable-boot-interrupt.patch file://uEnv.txt"

UBOOT_ENV = "uEnv"
UBOOT_ENV_SUFFIX = "txt"
```

More more note to be considered, if your Uboot is trying to fetch the `uEnv.txt` file from rootfs/boot then it is okay, but if it trying to get it from the `boot` partition (if you have one) then you should add it to that partition with (In your machine conf or local conf):

```bash
BOOT_FILES_append = " uEnv.txt"
```

Comment: I tried this, but uEnv.txt wasn't added to the boot directory.  (I'm not using a separate partition right now.)  I also tried to modify my do_install to make it look as close as possible to the code you showed from u-boot.inc, (```install -D -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/uEnv.txt ${D}/boot/uEnv.txt```) and that's not doing it either.  I never get compile errors, but no matter what I do, nothing shows up in the boot directory.

Comment: Go to `WORKDIR` of uboot and check the `image` folder, do you see a `boot` folder there ?

Comment: Well, that's interesting.  Yes, ```$WORKDIR/image/boot``` exists for the u-boot recipe, and my uEnv.txt is sitting there.  That's after running my code that is just using do_install (and not using the UBOOT_ENV variables).  But it isn't making it to ```$WORKDIR/rootfs/boot" for the core-image-minimal recipe.  Is there something I need to do to make that happen?

Comment: I think uboot is not added in the `IMAGE_INSTALL`, I don't think I saw this before, but I suggest creating other recipe for example `uboot-env.bb` to install the txt and add it `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " uboot-env"`

Comment: Creating another recipe worked, so it sounds like your theory was correct.  I have it working just using an install command in a do_install.  Eventually I may go back and see if I can make it work with a the UBOOT_ENV approach but from a separate recipe.

Comment: You cannot set `UBOOT_ENV` from a separate recipe, the variable is specific to Uboot recipe, it should be a `bbappend` for uboot, you can check other uboot examples that uses `UBOOT_ENV`.